# What does it mean "Do not recreate the service, unless there are pending intents to deliver."?

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent, restart, sticky

I handle Service and the return code: START_NOT_STICKY. I do not want to restart the service.

But documentation says "Do not recreate the service, unless there *are pending intents to deliver*." 
Could you give me an example of these pending intents that cause restarting the service?

Comment: Do you have an intentservice ?

Comment: No, I extend Service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `START_NOT_STICKY`, this means the following:

If Android kills the process hosting your `Service` (which it can pretty much do at any time if it needs the resources or if it thinks your `Service` isn't doing anything useful), the following happens:

- If your process is killed **after** `onStartCommand()` is called, but **before** `onStartCommand()` has completed, Android will restart your `Service` and call `onStartCommand()` again, redelivering the `Intent` that was being processed when the process was killed
- If your process is killed **after** `onStartCommand()` has completed, Android will only restart your `Service` if there are pending `Intent`s for your `Service`. In this case a pending `Intent` would exist if any component called `startService()` for your `Service` and that call has not yet been completely processed by your `Service`. This could be the case, for example, if a component called `startService()` while your `Service` was dead. Or it could happen if a component called `startService()` while your `Service` was still in the `onStartCommand()` method (processing a previous call to `startService()`).

Comment: Do I understand it well?
Let's say that I have an AlarmManager that starts a service every 30 minutes to do smth on the server. 

1. The service is performing a task.
2. The Android system stops the service because of the low memory.
3. Then the service is recreated with the same intent that was passed to onStartCommand() method?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In this case you can tell that your `Service` was restarted and the `Intent` is being redelivered because the call to `onStartCommand()` will contain the flag `START_FLAG_RETRY`.